# Showing that the number of ways to cut a 200 x 3 board into 1 x 2 dominoes is divisible by 3.

Tags: combinatorics, logic, tiling

Showing that the number of ways to cut a 200 x 3 board into 1 x 2 dominoes is divisible by 3.

My only idea is to assume the opposite, make some needed arrangement, and to show that changing the arrangement won't change the divisibility. Not sure how to implement it though.

Comment: I think a better idea would be to consider a smaller board, say $2\times 3$, and show it for that board, and then use that result to show that the corresponding statement is true for a $4\times 3$ board, and then generalize to an inductive proof showing that if a $2k\times 3$ board can be cut up in some number of ways that is a multiple of 3, then the same is true for a $(2k+2)\times 3$ board.  Working out the details for the small boards will also give you some ideas for handling the larger boards, and since you have only one idea now, getting more ideas would be a good move.

Comment: @MJD: It isn’t true for the $4\times 3$ board. It turns out to be true for the $2n\times 3$ board iff $n\equiv1\pmod3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of cutting up the board, I’ll tile it with dominoes. There are $3$ ways to tile a $2\times 3$ board. Say that a tiling of a $2n\times 3$ board is *irreducible* if it there is no $m\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that the tiling can be split into a $2m\times 3$ tiling and a $2(n-m)\times 3$ tiling. It’s not hard to see that for each $n\ge 2$ there are exactly $2$ irreducible tilings of the $2n\times 3$ board: one has a row of horizontal tiles along the top with all of the other tiles vertical, and the other has a row of horizontal tiles along the bottom with all of the other tiles vertical.

Each [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $n$ corresponds to one of the ways to divide the $2n\times 3$ board into smaller boards that are to be tiled irreducibly. If there are $k$ ones and $m$ larger integers in a composition of $n$, the composition gives rise to $3^k\cdot 2^m$ different tilings of the $2n\times 3$ board. If $k>0$ this is of course a multiple of $3$, so we’re interested in the compositions in which $k=0$, i.e., in which every part is at least $2$.

There are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts; if each has to be at least $2$, we’re looking at unrestricted compositions of $n-k$ into $k$ parts, of which there are $\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}$. Each part can be tiled irreducibly in $2\equiv-1\pmod3$ ways, so modulo $3$ each composition contributes $(-1)^k$ to the total number of tilings. Altogether, then, the number of tilings of the $2n\times 3$ board is congruent modulo $3$ to

$$\begin{align*}
t_n&\overset{\triangle}=\sum_k(-1)^k\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}\\\\
&=\sum_k(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n-2-k}k\\\\
&=\sum_k(-1)^{k+1}\left(\binom{n-3-k}k+\binom{n-3-k}{k-1}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_k(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n-3-k}k+\sum_k(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n-3-k}{k-1}\\\\
&=\sum_k(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n-3-k}k+\sum_k(-1)^k\binom{n-4-k}k\\\\
&=\sum_k(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n-3-k}k-\sum_k(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n-4-k}k\\\\
&=t_{n-1}-t_{n-2}\;.
\end{align*}$$

It’s easy enough to check that $t_2=t_3=1$, and an easy induction then shows that

$$t_n\bmod3=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }n\equiv1\pmod6\text{ or }n\equiv4\pmod6\\
1,&\text{if }n\equiv2\pmod6\text{ or }n\equiv5\pmod6\\
-1,&\text{if }n\equiv0\pmod6\text{ or }n\equiv3\pmod6\;.
\end{cases}$$

In particular, $100\equiv4\pmod6$, so the number of tilings of the $200\times 3$ board is a multiple of $3$.